# Why App is crashinhg sometime when create image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When i am creating image of the UIView, it crash **sometime**. please check below is the my code. and i am not able to recreate it.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(BillView.frame.size, BillView.isOpaque, 0.0)
 BillView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!) 
 let imgBill = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()! // Crash here
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Below is my crash from crash analytics.

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104f49098
>
> 0 Figment POS TransactionController.swift - Line 3654
> TransactionController.createBillImage() + 3654
>
> 1 Figment POS  - Line 4342993120 @objc
> TransactionController.createBillImage() + 4342993120
>
> 2 Foundation
> __NSFireDelayedPerform + 412
>
> 3 CoreFoundation
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 28
>
> 4 CoreFoundation
> __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 880
>
> 5 CoreFoundation
> __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 276
>
> 6 CoreFoundation
> __CFRunLoopRun + 1640
>
> 7 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
>
> 8 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 160
>
> 9 UIKitCore UIApplicationMain + 1932
>
> 10 Figment POS AppDelegate.swift - Line 39 main + 39
>
> 11 libdyld.dylib start + 4

Comment: Don't force unwrap the result of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` - Handle `nil` more gracefully.  Then your question becomes why is that function sometimes returning `nil`

Answer (score 0):

To safely unwrap a optional value you can use either `if-let` or `guard-let`.

For eg.

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
   print("graphic context is not available so you can not create an image.")
   return
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(BillView.frame.size, BillView.isOpaque, 0.0)
BillView.layer.render(in: context) 
if let imgBill = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
  //here you will get image for sure 
  print(imgBill.size)
} else {
  //this is the case when image is nil
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```